# limiting the size of an array?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Suppose we have the following code :

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;



sub print_ele_arr{

my @arr = <STDIN> ;
#print the elements of the array here . 
#do something else ..
    }
print_ele_arr() ;
```

but i want to store just 3 elements from the user's input into my @arr array , how to do that , in general how to limit the size of a given array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store just 3 lines, you can use

```
my $i = 1;
while (defined( my $line = <STDIN>) and $i++ <=3) {
    push @arr, $line;
}
```

As for the second question, what do you mean by limiting the size of an array? You can use an array slice to get just the first three elements of an array:

```
my @first_three = @arr[0 .. 2];
```

Comment: i mean something like preventing the user from typing more than 3 elements ?

Comment: If the user is entering elements on a single line then in general there is nothing you can do to control what he types as the software doesn't see the input until the enter key is hit. If you want to tell then off afterwards for an invalid entry then just count the number of fields they have typed.

Comment: It's wrong to read from terminal (whcih STDIN usaully is) after receiving an EOF from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

sub print_ele_arr {

  my @arr;
  while (@arr < 3) {
    push @arr, scalar <STDIN>;
  }

  # chomp(@arr); # remove newlines from @arr elements?
  print "@arr\n";
}

print_ele_arr() ;
```

When reading from `STDIN` or any other input file handle there are two ways to it, doing it in scalar or list context.

List context forces reading all lines at once, and scalar reads one line at the time. Since `STDIN` doesn't have fixed size, it's better to force scalar context, using `scalar` function.

This is necessary when populating array, and redundant when populating plain scalar, ie.

`my $single_line = <STDIN>;`

is same thing as writing

`my $single_line = scalar <STDIN>;`

Comment: It's wrong to read from terminal (whcih STDIN usaully is) after receiving an EOF from it.

Comment: `eof()` check should be applied?

Comment: No need, just stop when `<STDIN>` returns undef. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

> i mean something like preventing the user from typing more than 3 elements ?

No. There's no way for a computer to control a person or to physically lock the keyboard. They can type away all they want. They could even have typed more than three lines before you even read the first.

You have two options:

1. Read only the first three lines.

   ```
   my @lines;
   while (<>) {
      push @lines, $_;
      last if @lines == 3;
   }

   die "Bad input" if @lines < 3;
   ```
2. Throw an error if he types in more than three lines before sending an EOF.

   ```
   my @lines;
   while (<>) {
      die "Bad input" if @lines > 3;
      push @lines, $_;
   }

   die "Bad input" if @lines < 3;
   ```